# Angularjs - Bootstrap setting selected drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem in setting the selected dropdown value from the server.

```
<select **class="form-control input-sm"** placeholder="Choose Email" 
ng-model="groupForm.email"  
ng-options="agentListl.email for agentListl in agentList track by agentListl.id">
</select>
```

I set the previously selected value from the server by setting the id for groupForm.email.

With this select, It works fine. But when I change the class from class="form-control input-sm" to class="select-full", it is not setting the previously selected value. But i can get the selected value.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ng-model must be the reference of any item from your array like `groupform.email = useragentlistl[0]`

Comment: I tired the same way. Still it is not working with the class select-full. 

$.each($scope.agentList, function(i) {
           
      if($scope.agentList[i].id == data.email){
       selectedAgent= $scope.agentList[i];
      }
     });